# Why are my dotnet 5.0 mvc form fields retaining their input values on post?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-5

I have an dot net 5.0 mvc page which takes a model object (ClassFoo) which when constructed generates an instance of (classBar). ClassBar has various properties (FieldA, FieldB, FieldC) all are strings.

The Views content is all in a form and the form's input fields are all from ClassFoo.ClassBar's various properties. Initially, when the page is accessed, all form input values are empty. However when I put data into them and then submit the form, the form values are still there when the page loads. However I don't understand why this is because I'm explicitly creating a new model during the controller operation but I am not actually populating the Model.ClassBar with the content from the post before I return model to the View for generation.

What I would expect is that all of the form fields would be empty however that is not the case. I know if asp.net the form values are stored and restored automatically but I didn't think that happened in mvc.

Comment: This is likely due to the attempted values being restored from the ModelState

Comment: @NickAlbrecht and that "ModelState" is different than the Model that I pass directly to the view?

Comment: One of the things it does, is hold the attempted values when trying to submit your form. This is so that if there is a validation problem (server-side), and you re-display the form to give the user a chance to make corrections, it shows the attempted values, and not the values from the viewmodel. If your submission was successful, and you want to display a blank form, try calling `ModelState.Clear()` and see if that fixes your problem

Comment: I'll look into this. Thanks Nick.

Answer (score 1):

After looking into ModelState recommended by Nick Albrech in the comments I reviewed the hint associated w/ the HtmlHelper.TextBoxFor() which states the following:

> ... Adds a "value" attribute to the element containing the first non-null value found in: the ActionContext.ModelState entry with full name, or the expression evaluated against ViewDataDictionary.Model. See [IHtmlHelper.NameFor] for more information about a "full name".

So effectively what's happening is similar to what I thought asp.net mvc wasn't doing in that it populates the ModelState from a get/post request with the name and values of the form being submitted. Then based on the use of these helper functions (and also asp-for attributes used in razor views views), it either provides values from the saved model state form values OR the model passed to the view. *Note: this does not seem to work if you set the value of an input element = @Model.[someProperty]*

The take away from this is that you do not necessarily need to update your model object with content from the previous form submit in order to have the page populate the form contents back to the screen. Allow asp.net mvc to do the manual tasks by making use of these razor helpers.

Shoutout to Nick for the assist on this one. A solid member of the stackOverflow community.